# how to do recursive replacement with incremented alphanumeric value in a file using sed/awk/perl

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed

How can I make shell script using Sed or awk for recursive replacement of same value with incremented alphanumeric values and inside again recursive with incremented alphanumeric values. It should happen till nth value to end of file

---Input file as follow----

```
<first line has same value as testname="tran cont" enabled="true">
    <inner first line has url testname="/" enabled="true">
    <inner second line has url testname="/test/dui/views?" enabled="true">
<first line has same value as testname="tran cont" enabled="true">
    <inner first line has url testname="/test/TeDi/perf" enabled="true">
    <inner second line has url testname="/Dest/Content/surf" enabled="true">
    <inner third line has url testname="/Cest/dui/duff" enabled="true">
<first line has same value as testname="tran cont" enabled="true">
     <inner first line has url testname="/test/dui/complete" enabled="true">
     <inner second line has url testname="/test/dui/one" enabled="true">
     <inner third line has url testname="/test/dui/two" enabled="true">
```

---output required as follow----

```
<first line has same value as testname="A01" enabled="true">
    <inner first line has url testname="A01_01" enabled="true">
    <inner second line has url testname="A01_02_views?" enabled="true">
<first line has same value as testname="A02" enabled="true">
    <inner first line has url testname="A02_01_perf" enabled="true">
    <inner second line has url testname="A02_02_surf" enabled="true">
    <inner third line has url testname="A02_03_duff" enabled="true">
<first line has same value as testname="A03" enabled="true">
    <inner first line has url testname="A03_01_complete" enabled="true">
    <inner second line has url testname="A03_02_one" enabled="true">
    <inner third line has url testname="A03_03_two" enabled="true">
```

Comment: you better copy a little part of your real text, otherwise after someone posting answers, there must be `ping-pang` rounds. E.g. how do we know `first line has` and `innter first`... are there any fixed pattern we could use? I don't think `first` or `inner` would be the ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some to get you going:

```
awk  -F\" '/^<first/ {a++;b=0} {n=split($2,s,"/");q=s[n];$2="A0"a ($0~/<inner/?"_0"++b"_"q:"")}1' OFS=\" file
<first line has same value as testname="A01" enabled="true">
    <inner first line has url testname="A01_01_" enabled="true">
    <inner second line has url testname="A01_02_views?" enabled="true">
<first line has same value as testname="A02" enabled="true">
    <inner first line has url testname="A02_01_perf" enabled="true">
    <inner second line has url testname="A02_02_surf" enabled="true">
    <inner third line has url testname="A02_03_duff" enabled="true">
<first line has same value as testname="A03" enabled="true">
     <inner first line has url testname="A03_01_complete" enabled="true">
     <inner second line has url testname="A03_02_one" enabled="true">
     <inner third line has url testname="A03_03_two" enabled="true">
```

---

How it works:

```
awk  -F\" '                                 # Set field separator to "
/^<first/ {                                 # If record starts with <first then do:
    a++                                     # Increment variable a
    b=0}                                    # Set b to 0
    {                                       # For all run do:
    n=split($2,s,"/")                       # Split data in field 2, to array s slitted by /. Sen variable n to number of data in array s
    q=s[n]                                  # Set variable q to last element in array s
    $2="A0"a ($0~/<inner/?"_0"++b"_"q:"")   # Set field 2 to: "A0" + value of a + ( if $0 equal "inner" to "_0" b (auto increment) "_" q, else "") 
    }
1                                           # Print the line
' OFS=\" file                               # Set Output Field Separator to " and read the file
```

Comment: Hi Jotne, thanks for your help. can you explain me in elaborated way. One more thing how i can handle suppose i have lines as follow. <first line has same value as testname="tran cont" enabled="true">
    <inner first "line" has url testname="/" enabled="true">
    <inner "second" line has "url" testname="/test/dui/views?" enabled="true">            <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</boolProp>
            <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
          </HTTPSamplerProxy>